# Importlib import_module from another package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, import-module, python-importlib

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── superclass
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── superclass.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_subclass.pyc
└── subclass
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    └── subclass.py
```

In `subclass.py` I have a class `Subclass`, which inherits from `Superclass`. In `Subclass.__init__`, I call `self.register("subclass", ["a", "b"])`, which is defined in `Superclass` as:

```
def register(self, package, module_names):
  for name in module_names:
    module = importlib.import_module(name, package)
    functions = inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)
    for register in functions:
      if register[0].startswith("register"):
        register[1](self)
```

`subclass.py` also contains:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  Subclass().do_something()
```

When I run `python subclass/subclass.py`, everything works as I expect; modules `a` and `b` are imported, and all the `register` functions in each module are run correctly.

In `test_subclass`, I have `from subclass.subclass import Subclass`, and I call the `Subclass` constructor. However, when I run `py.test`, I get the error `ImportError: No module named b`. The `a` module imports fine, but the `b` module fails.

I tried reversing the order of imports (`self.register("subclass", ["b", "a"])`, and it still failed on `b`.

Module `a` has *more* import statements than module `b` (I have other files not shown in the directory diagram), and it still fails the same way when I add all of `a`'s imports to `b`.

Is this the right way of importing modules dynamically? If so, am I missing something? If not, am I passing the wrong arguments to `import_module`?

Note, I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Adding the parent path of `subclass` to PYTHONPATH , does that help?

Comment: A good thought, but I already made sure it was there. Thanks